# Why are the Indriyas attributed to Manomaya Kosha and not Annamaya Kosha? Similarly Karma Indriya's in pranamayakosha?

Tags: indriyas

The indriyas are attributed to manomaya kosha, and karmendriyas are attributed to pramayakosha. But arent these sense organs part of the physical body.

Does this mean indriya's are not the physical sense organ but something more subtler?

Comment: Can a dead body see, hear, taste etc?

Comment: correct. indriyas are the metaphysical organ behind the gross physical organ like eyes. there are people with ears who can't hear, people with eyes who can't see and so on. in the case of ear implants letting people hear, it is simply an amplification of the gross organ, like eye-glasses to help someone see better. they don't/can't magically initiate  dead indriyas